# Novel about a spaceship in a distortion, a galaxy appears around a corpse

Tags: story-identification, novel

Well, I'm asking for help from other SF fans because I'm trying to recover the title of a novel I read years ago...

Obviously I don't remember the title or the author. I remember that the plot was about a spaceship that, for some reason, finds itself in a distortion due to which it begins to increase in volume (I think it's something like that).

An image that I remember well is that at a certain point, in the central area of said spaceship, where a corpse had been placed, something milky appears and gets bigger. At the beginning the crew thinks it is a ghost but as time goes by they realize that it is a galaxy.

Comment: Do you have any idea how many years ago you read this?

Comment: @KerrAvon Funny to see your username here; I was just thinking this sounds vaguely like one or two episodes of Blake's Seven, except for the galaxy part.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I read it about 20 years ago. Luckly enough I see that someone has found out the title and the author!

Comment: @LSerni thank you so very much! Yes, that's the book I was seraching for! Time for me to grab it back and read it once more! Again, thank you a lot!

Comment: @The Great Assyr - If LSerni's answer is correct, please mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

It is a novel by Bob Shaw, about the voyages of an exploratory ship. I distinctly remember the scene you refer to - when Captain Aesop says something like, "At four thirty-two this morning, an object with the features of a ghost has been observed emerging from Mr. ...'s corpse".

I too read this some thirty years ago, but in Italian.

From the cover that describes the first tale in the book (it has to be the first tale since it deals with Captain Aesop's identity), I'd say it is "[Ship of Strangers](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/s/bob-shaw/ship-of-strangers.htm)".

I keep confusing this with A.E.Van Vogt's *The voyages of the Space Beagle* because two characters have similar names.

[image: Cover of "Ship of Strangers" by Bob Shaw. The cover shows a blue spaceship standing on several legs, shooting something and causing several yellow explosions nearby. A truck on treads is seen heading towards the ship. The scene is set against a starry night background.]

Comment: If accepted, duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66931/28516 (I agree that this is the correct answer)